# Frobenius’ Method to Solve an ODE (Hydrogen Atom - Radial Equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, special-functions, quantum-groups

My goal is to find two linearly independent solutions to the ODE

$$
r^2\frac{d^2R}{dr^2}+2r\frac{dR}{dr}+[r^2+\lambda r-l(l+1)]R=0
$$

in the interval $[0,\infty)\ni r$, where $R=R(r)$, and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}_+$ and $l\in\mathbb{Z}_0$ are fixed constants. Just to put in context my problem, this ODE determined the radial component of the wavefunction of an electron in an atom. The standard approach (e.g. [here](http://www.reed.edu/physics/courses/p342.s10/physics342/page1/files/lecture.24.pdf)) is to investigate the asymptotic behaviour of the equation for large and small $r$, factor out this behaviour and then use a series to try to find the solution of what's left. Nonetheless, I'm looking for an answer of the form: ''The general solution to this ODE is given by $R(r)=c_1y_1(r)+c_2y_2$, but since $R(0)$ must be well-defined and $y_2(r)\to-\infty$ as $r\to0$, then $c_2=0$ for the answer to be physically acceptable''. I know that the ''physically acceptable'' solution is given by

$$
y_1\propto\left(\frac{2r}{n}\right)^le^{-r/n}L^{2l+1}_{n+l}\left(\frac{2r}{n}\right)
$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, and where $L^{2l+1}_{n+l}$ are the associated Laguerre polynomials.

My attempt to find $y_1$ and $y_2$ is to use Frobenius’ method, but i keep stuck at some point: since $r=0$ is a regular singular point of the differential equation, there exists at least one solution of the form

$$
R(r)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kr^{k+s}
$$

where $s$ are indicial roots to be found. Then

$$
\frac{dR}{dr}(r)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+s)c_kr^{k+s-1}\quad\text{and}\quad\frac{d^2R}{dr^2}(r)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+s)(k+s-1)c_kr^{k+s-2}
$$

and so, substituting in the equation, it yields

\begin{align} 
0&=r^s\Biggl[c_0[s(s+1)-l(l+1)]+(c_1[(s+1)(s+2)-l(l+1)]+\lambda c_0)r \\
 &\quad+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\Bigl(c_k[(k+s)(k+s-1)+2(k+s)-l(l+1)]+c_{k-2}+\lambda c_{k-1}\Bigr)r^k\Biggr] 
\end{align}

The first term gives me the indicial roots

$$
c_0[s(s+1)-l(l+1)]=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad s_1=l\quad\text{and}\quad s_2=-l-1
$$

and because nothing is gained by taking $c_0=0$. Now, since $s_1$ and $s_2$ are distinct and the difference $s_1-s_2=2l+1$ is a positive integer, then there exist two linearly independent solutions of the form

$$
R^1(r)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_kr^{k+l},\quad c_0\neq0
$$

and

$$
R^2(r)=CR^1(r)\ln(r)+\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_kr^{k-l-1}
$$

where $C$ is a constant that could be zero (I'm following the book ''Differential Equations with Boundary-Value Problems; DENNIS G. ZILL and MICHAEL R. CULLEN''.) For the second term

$$
c_1[(s+1)(s+2)-l(l+1)]+\lambda c_0=0
$$

from where

$$
c_1=\frac{l+l^2-\lambda c_0}{2+3l+l^2}\quad\text{for $s_1=l$},\quad\text{and}\quad c_1=\frac{l+l^2-\lambda c_0}{l(l-1)}\quad\text{for $s_2=-l-1$}
$$

For $k\geq2$, I have

$$
c_k[(k+s)(k+s-1)+2(k+s)-l(l+1)]+c_{k-2}+\lambda c_{k-1}=0
$$

> How can I continue from here to find the solution/series $R^1(r)$ and $R^2(r)$ ? How are they ?
>
> Is there a better way to proceed in order to find $R^1(r)$ and $R^2(r)$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just need to solve for $c_{k}$ in your last line now. This generates the values of the coefficients from $c_{0}$ and $c_{1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Follow the method in http://science.fire.ustc.edu.cn/download/download1/book%5Cmathematics%5CHandbook%20of%20Exact%20Solutions%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20EquationsSecond%20Edition%5Cc2972_fm.pdf#page=250:

Let $R=r^kS$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dR}{dr}=r^k\dfrac{dS}{dr}+kr^{k-1}S$

$\dfrac{d^2R}{dr^2}=r^k\dfrac{d^2S}{dr^2}+kr^{k-1}\dfrac{dS}{dr}+kr^{k-1}\dfrac{dS}{dr}+k(k-1)r^{k-2}S=r^k\dfrac{d^2S}{dr^2}+2kr^{k-1}\dfrac{dS}{dr}+k(k-1)r^{k-2}S$

$\therefore r^2\left(r^k\dfrac{d^2S}{dr^2}+2kr^{k-1}\dfrac{dS}{dr}+k(k-1)r^{k-2}S\right)+2r\left(r^k\dfrac{dS}{dr}+kr^{k-1}S\right)+(r^2+\lambda r-l(l+1))r^kS=0$

$r^{k+2}\dfrac{d^2S}{dr^2}+2kr^{k+1}\dfrac{dS}{dr}+k(k-1)r^kS+2r^{k+1}\dfrac{dS}{dr}+2kr^kS+(r^2+\lambda r-l(l+1))r^kS=0$

$r^{k+2}\dfrac{d^2S}{dr^2}+2(k+1)r^{k+1}\dfrac{dS}{dr}+(r^2+\lambda r+k(k+1)-l(l+1))r^kS=0$

$r^2\dfrac{d^2S}{dr^2}+2(k+1)r\dfrac{dS}{dr}+(r^2+\lambda r+k(k+1)-l(l+1))S=0$

Choose $k=l$ , the ODE becomes

$r^2\dfrac{d^2S}{dr^2}+2(l+1)r\dfrac{dS}{dr}+(r^2+\lambda r)S=0$

$r\dfrac{d^2S}{dr^2}+2(l+1)\dfrac{dS}{dr}+(r+\lambda)S=0$